# c++ wait for system call

Tags: c++, system, call

I am working with files in C++.
I call a program on system prompt to create a txt file. Then I use C++ to read that file.
I need to make sure C++ wait for the program to finish before read the file.

An explanation C++:

```
createOutputFile(); 
system("Start wp/PRO386W.EXE /V1 consult('wp/read.pl').");
// I need to wait for this "PRO386W.EXE to finish
readLista();//before calling this method
```

Comment: Use `CreateProcess` instead of `system()` and you can wait on the returned handle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

system() waits for the command to complete. In your case, the "command" is "start" and that forces it to the background. Remove the "start" and you should be fine. If you really need for it to be asynchronous, you'll need to launch the process differently.

Comment: I tried system("wp/PRO386W.EXE /V1 consult('wp/read.pl')."); and it did not work either.

Comment: It did not work because you cannot launch programs like that on Windows. Use CreateProcess and wait on the handle that CreateProcess returns.

Comment: It works now, I used something like:

system("\"wp/PRO386W.EXE\" /V1 consult('wp/read.pl').");

Answer (score 1):

If the program `WP/PRO386W.exe` is a console program, just remove `Start`, which makes the program run in background. UPD: maybe you'll have to use backslash: `"WP\\PRO386W.exe ..."`.

Answer (score -4):

You can always check for end of file. Assuming fin is of type ifstream then you can check f (!fin.eof( ))

Comment: Wha... I don't think you understand what `istream::eof` checks or what it means.